# How can we get the interaction hamilton $H_\text{int}$ from the Lagrange $L$?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory, interactions

After we quantize  the free field we continue on determining the form of $H$. We can impose, by example:

$$H=H_0+\lambda V_\text{int}$$

My question is, can we determine $H_\text{int}$ by the interaction term of the Lagrange $L$? (through canonical quantization?)  What if we follow path integral?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): If you want an answer beyond the naive answer $H_{\rm int}= -L_{\rm int}$, you likely need to be more specific.

Comment: What if we follow the path integral? How can we obtain the same result?